# typescript class decorator can not access static value if decorator return as high order function

Tags: typescript, decorator

Here is a demo:

```
function Bar(FooClass: Foo) {
  console.log('in Bar decorator');

  return function (args) {
    console.log('in Bar high order function: ', args);
    let foo = new FooClass();
  }
}

@Bar
class Foo {

  a = 1;
  static b = 2;

  constructor(args) {
    console.log('in Foo constructor')
    console.log('Foo instance a: ', this.a);
    console.log('Foo static b: ', Foo.b);
  }
}

new Foo(123);
```

When I compile the code and run it, it prints:

```
in Bar decorator
in Bar high order function:  123
in Foo constructor
Foo instance a:  1
Foo static b:  undefined
```

I know I can access the static value `b` in the high order function by `FooClass.b`. But it seems I can not access it in the instance of `Foo`.

Comment: Your code does not compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way decorators work is that if you return a value from the decorator, that will replace the decorated class. The function you return can successfully replace `Foo` but since it does not inherit the properties of the original `Foo` it will not be available on the replaced `Foo`.

The simplest solution is to return an anonymous class that derives from the class that is passed to the decorator.

```
function Bar(FooClass: typeof Foo) {
    console.log('in Bar decorator');
    return class extends FooClass {
        constructor(args: any) {
            super(args);
            console.log('in Bar high order function: ', args);
        }
    };
}

@Bar
class Foo {

    a = 1;
    static b = 2;
    constructor(args: any) {
        console.log('in Foo constructor')
        console.log('Foo instance a: ', this.a);
        console.log('Foo static b: ', Foo.b);
    }
}

new Foo(123);
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my day!